# Remove array from multi-dimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, slice

I build menu on the backend, populated by an array and sub-arrays.
**The structure is on config.php**..

```
$primary_nav = array(
   array(
        'name'  => 'Μέλη',
        'url'   => 'member_list.php',
        'icon'  => 'fa fa-users',
        'access'=> 0
    ),array(
        'name'  => 'Ημερίδες',
        'url'   => ($usr['access_level'] == 1) ? 'imerides_list.php':'javascript:void(0)',
        'icon'  => 'fa fa-bullhorn',
        'access'=> 1
    )
);
```

On Class Users, where it retrieves the access level, i added

```
if($row['access_level'] != 1){
    unset($primary_nav[1]);
}
```

How can i do it like, `if access level == 1`, remove the array `parent`?

I tried `unset($primary_nav[1])` and `array_slice` but they are not working.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: "remove the array parent" - that would be which one?

Comment: Array parent, would be the $primary_nav[1], if access_level==1 on this array. The whole child array might be better

Comment: What was it about `unset($primary_nav[1])` and `array_slice()` that didn't work? What effect did you get from them? What was it about that effect that wasn't suitable to your needs? Also, did you try `array_splice()` rather than `array_slice()`? And what about taking a whole different approach and building the menu up according to permissions rather than cutting it down.

Comment: When i say not working, i mean the array is not removed..

Comment: still not clear.need the code you used or an example scenario...

Comment: wouldn't it be easier if you don't populate the array with things you don't want in first place?

Comment: It's about member access level. I need everything and then remove. Menu is static, so i need to remove..

Comment: are you mis understood, do you know $primary_nav[1] is array(
        'name'  => 'Ημερίδες',
        'url'   => ($usr['access_level'] == 1) ? 'imerides_list.php':'javascript:void(0)',
        'icon'  => 'fa fa-bullhorn',
        'access'=> 1
    ) and $primary_nav[0] is what you are trying to remove?? may be..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry people, I just noticed, i am saying, Class Users, where it is Class Users and user is a public function, not passing in $primary_nav, that is why it didn't see the array to unset it...

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This is the complete answer...$primary_nav array was not passed on the public function on Class "Users" in order to be readable and edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following:

```
$primary_nav = array(
   array(
        'name'  => 'Μέλη',
        'url'   => 'member_list.php',
        'icon'  => 'fa fa-users',
        'access'=> 0
    ),array(
        'name'  => 'Ημερίδες',
        'url'   => 'test',
        'icon'  => 'fa fa-bullhorn',
        'access'=> 1
    )
);

foreach($primary_nav as $index=>$obj){
    if($obj['access']==1){
        unset($primary_nav[$index]);
    }
}

print_r($primary_nav);
```

Comment: He is talking about '$usr['access_level']' not '$obj['access']'

Comment: Hmmm now i understand. @MahaDev same approach can me followed for  `'$usr['access_level']` also.

Comment: Still not removing the array..unset is not removing the array

Answer (score 0):

```
Try It ,May Help You .
$primary_nav = array(
   array(
        'name'  => 'Sourabh',
        'url'   => 'member_list.php',
        'icon'  => 'fa fa-users',
        'access'=> 0
    ),array(
        'name'  => 'Nigam',
        'url'   => ($usr['access_level'] == 1) ? 'imerides_list.php':'javascript:void(0)',
        'icon'  => 'fa fa-bullhorn',
        'access'=> 1
    )
);
foreach ($primary_nav as $key=>$primary) {
    foreach ($primary as $vkey=>$value) {
        if($vkey=='access' AND $value==1){
            unset($primary_nav[$key]);
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($primary_nav);
```

Comment: Care to enlighten us as to what your code does and how it answers the question?